# JavaFx custom design button click detect in used application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

Created custom design using FXML with two files CustomToggleSwitch.fxml and CustomToggleSwitch.java.

CustomToggleSwitch.fxml has following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root type="Pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
 <children>
    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#click" text="Button" />
 </children>
</fx:root>
```

CustomToggleSwitch.java has code

```
package com.custom;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class CustomToggleSwitch extends Pane{
   int tick;

   public CustomToggleSwitch() {

      FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CustomToggleSwitch.fxml"));
      loader.setRoot(this);
      loader.setController(this);

       try {
          loader.load();            
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }

  @FXML 
  public void click(ActionEvent actionEvent){
     System.out.println(tick++);
  }
}
```

Created jar file from these and used this jar file inside application project. Application has test.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.custom.*?>
<?import com.custom.CustomToggleSwitch?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-   Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"   xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
    <CustomToggleSwitch layoutX="29.0" layoutY="48.0" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller class(TestController.java) has following

```
public class TestController implements Initializable{

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    }

    @FXML 
    public void click(){
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Button is shown successfully on GUI and Button click is also get detected.Button is showing 0,1,2,3..etc on output console. But Test is not getting printed on screen.

**How can i detect button press in application controller class?** Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks a lot to all.

Comment: add listener property with getter and setter in your component controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> add listener property with getter and setter in your component
>   controller.

The example of Jai is correct, but inconsistent with the other components of javafx. For proper implementation, it is appropriate to use properties that can be manipulated in both FXML and manual mode.

This is the user component controller that has an onMyAction property added. This property is used for event notification.

```
public class CustomToggleSwitch extends Pane {

    private ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> onMyAction = new SimpleObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>>();

    public CustomToggleSwitch() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/CustomToggleSwitch.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);

        try {
            loader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void click(ActionEvent event) {
        if(onMyAction.get() != null) {
            onMyAction.get().handle(event);
        }
    }

    public EventHandler<ActionEvent> getOnMyAction() {
        return onMyAction.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> onMyActionProperty() {
        return onMyAction;
    }

    public void setOnMyAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> onMyAction) {
        this.onMyAction.set(onMyAction);
    }
}
```

With such a structured component, the onMyAction property can be added by FXML for example

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
    <CustomToggleSwitch onMyAction="#testHandler"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

---

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private void testHandler(ActionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

or manually

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
    <CustomToggleSwitch fx:id="customToggleSwitch"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

---

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private CustomToggleSwitch customToggleSwitch;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        customToggleSwitch.setOnMyAction(event -> {

        });
    }

}
```

---

**Update**

> You don't need to use a property. Making the getter and setter available should be sufficient to use it from fxml. (I didn't encountered a case where I would add a listerner to a event handler property yet.)

This is a conversion without the use of Property

```
public class CustomToggleSwitch extends Pane {

    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> myEventHandler;

    public CustomToggleSwitch() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/CustomToggleSwitch.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);

        try {
            loader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void click(ActionEvent event) {
        if(myEventHandler != null) {
            myEventHandler.handle(event);
        }
    }

    public EventHandler<ActionEvent> getOnMyAction() {
        return myEventHandler;
    }

    public void setOnMyAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> onMyAction) {
        myEventHandler = onMyAction;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use a property. Making the getter and setter available should be sufficient to use it from fxml. (I didn't encountered a case where I would add a listerner to a event handler property yet.)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `onAction="#click"` is declared in CustomToggleSwitch.fxml, so `FXMLLoader` will look for the `click()` in CustomToggleSwitch.java.

Adding a `click()` in `TestController` class is not going to do anything, because you do not have any node with `onAction="#click"` in test.fxml.

One way for the `Button` in CustomToggleSwitch to communicate with `TestController` class is to relay the event out.

```
public class CustomToggleSwitch extends Pane {
    // Same stuff

    private List<Runnable> onClickRunnables = new ArrayList<>();

    public final void addButtonOnClickRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(runnable);
        onClickRunnables.add(runnable);
    }

    @FXML 
    private void click(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        System.out.println(tick++);
        if (!onClickRunnables.isEmpty()) {
            onClickRunnables.forEach(r -> r.run());
        }
    }
}


public class TestController implements Initializable {
    // Give CustomToggleSwitch control an fx:id in FXML
    @FXML private CustomToggleSwitch customSwitch;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        customSwitch.addButtonOnClickRunnable(this::click);
    }
}
```

Another way is to expose the `Button` in `CustomToggleSwitch` out. Personally, I would suggest against this because it's neater to keep implementation of a "control" hidden.